# Given $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_A(f_{n+1}-f_n)^2d\mu=0$ ,$ \int_Xf_n^2d\mu \le k $, is {$f_n $} uniformly integrable on $A$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Given $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_A(f_{n+1}-f_n)^2d\mu=0$ , is {$f_n $} uniformly integrable on $A$ ?

$ f_n: R \to R $

$ n \in N $

$\mu$ is Lebesgue outer measure, $ A $  is a measurable set with finite measure. $ \int_Xf_n^2d\mu \le k $ where $ k \in R $ , $ X \subseteq A $

Comment: What is the measure? Lebesgue? Or an arbitrary measure? Finite or not finite?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter, the answer is no for any measure and any $A$, as long as there exists $E\subset A$ with $0<\mu(E)<\infty$. Which is to say the answer is no unless $\mu(A)=0$, in which case the question is just stupid, or $\mu$ is a very strange measure.

Comment: @Shashi measure is assumed yo be countably additive, sorry about the incomplete question.

Comment: @Abdullahi_A_Ibrahim still vague. You mean $f_n$ instead of $f$ right? Somewhere you write $X$ but you mean $A$ right?

Comment: @Shashi thanks. I made corrections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question keeps changing, and the quantifiers are still a bit unclear as of now. If we're assuming that $\int_Xf_n^2\le k$ for *every* $X\subset A$ then the answer is yes, even without assuming that $\int_A(f_n-f_{n+1})^2\to0$.

Because then $\int_Af_n^2\le k$, so Cauchy-Schwarz shows that $$\int_E|f_n|\le\mu(E)^{1/2}k^{1/2}$$for every $E\subset A$.

Comment: Sorry my question was incomplete when u posted thus

Comment: @Abdullahi_A_Ibrahim What does $ \int_Xf^2d\mu \le k $  have to do with anything here? There's no "$f$" anywhere else in the question.

Comment: I made corrections.

Comment: I was thinking "heh? The first condition must come somewhere?". I was so uncertain about my proof, but seeing yours made me certain about it. There is also no need to write my proof since I did not use Cauchy-Schwarz which made my proof way too long for something that can be done with almost one-line lol.